# No suspend option in UI on Bionic Beaver

Tags: suspend, 18.04

There is no suspend option in desktop 18.04. The only way I found is to go to **Settings > power options** and to set it to suspend when pressing the start button.

It works but I need to log in every time and it's painfully slow to open up.

Answer (score 20):

Open the status menu (upper right corner) and hold alt, the shutdown button will turn into a suspend button as long as you're pressing alt (or long press with the left mouse on the shutdown button and it will turn in to a suspend button). There are also extensions that provide both buttons at the same time without requiring this extra step.

Comment: Thanks. Mind a link to those extensions ?

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/826/suspend-button/